# Customizing UINavigationBar not working because of weird UINavigationBar view hierarchy

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uivisualeffectview, view-hierarchy, uinavigationbarappearance

My app has many ViewControllers that are pushed on navigation stack.

I have configured UINavigationBar appearance globally in AppDelegate as below.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
appearance.barTintColor = myColor
appearance.tintColor = .white
appearance.isTranslucent = false
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                      NSAttributedString.Key.font: myFont, size: mySize)]
appearance.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
```

All ViewControllers work as expected except only one ViewController.

Below is one of the VCs that works as expected. It shows color and font that I want.

[image]

And below is the ViewController that shows different look unlike others.

[image]

I can't understand the reason why only one navigationBar on this VC shows different appearance.

So I've done debugging view hierarchy.

Below is the view hierarchy of VCs that works as expected.

[image]

And below is the view hierarchy of VC that shows weird look.

[image]

As seen on the picture, the problematic NavigationBar has two more layers, UIVisualEffectView and UIVisualEffectBackdropView.

I am an experienced iOS developer and have no idea why this happens.

I carefully checked all the setting related to NavigationBar on the IB but found no difference from others.

I even removed the ViewController, embedding NavigationController completely and rebuilt them from scratch without luck.

Please somebody explain me why only this NavigationBar has different structure.

I'm working on iOS 13.3 & Xcode 11.3.1

Comment: Have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Working here on iOS15, I tried a lot of things to customize the nav bar appearance to achieve a simple opaque color, nothing worked except this:

In viewDidLoad

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        UINavigationBarAppearance *appearance = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
         appearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
}
```

Swift version:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.backgroundColor = .orange
navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance
```

Finally if you only want to apply this on the current controller, and restore the default nav bar just do the same but with a fresh UINavigationBarAppearance() on viewWillDisappear.